# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ApplicationIdentity.FullName

Tags: .net

I've been using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ApplicationIdentity.FullName to get the name of the executing application from a DLL that is called by the app but have just discovered that AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ApplicationIdentity can be null resulting in a null reference exception.

Couple of questions:

Is there a more reliable way to get the name of the executing application from a called DLL?

Under what use cases would AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ApplicationIdentity be null?

Thanks.

Comment: In what scenarios are you seeing it appear as a null reference exception?

Answer (score 1):

You might try System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name

Answer (score 0):

If the application hasn't been deployed/published yet, `ApplicationIdentity` is null.

See also: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/355467/Getting-publishing-information-for-a-ClickOnce-dep